# What is the appropriate character encoding for a git repo?

Tags: git, character-encoding

Specifically what encoding to use if the repo has both code and docs? Any .md or .htm files are saved as UTF-8, but code is cp1252 (my compiler doesn't like the 3-byte BOM which Windows adds to UTF-8 files).

As seen in Git GUI tool (Edit -> Options...):

[image: As seen in Git GUI tool]

Frankly, does it even matter what setting I choose?

My system is Windows 8.1, and the system encoding is `cp1252`

Comment: Not using a braindead editor sounds like easily the superior fix.

Comment: Or even switching to an actual [Braindead editor](https://github.com/hellerve/e)! (seriously, I agree with your comment, need to get my act together).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The setting in git GUI only sets the *default* encoding. Real encoding should be set via [.gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_viewing_files_in_gui_tools). For example:

```
echo '*.html encoding=utf-8' >> .gitattributes
echo '*.c encoding=cp1252' >> .gitattributes
```

PS. What editor do you use that you cannot configure BOM in it? I recommend to disable BOM and use one encoding for all text files.

Comment: Thanks for this, I guess it's time to configure my setup properly, and then stick with UTF-8 all the way!

Comment: filesystem-native, file and program-native character sets are all independent, counting the user interface as a separate "file".  cp1047 files on a filesystem that names files with custom-composed UTF-16, processed by a utf-8 native program and merged int a cp1252 dataset for windows-95-mindset phb's has no doubt been seen in the wild.

Comment: Where are the valid encoding values listed?

Comment: @daniol `git` (just like any other) uses [`libiconv`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) so you can try `iconv -l` in the command line.

Comment: Should it be `encoding=` or `working-tree-encoding=`?

Comment: @endolith `encoding`. The user doesn't want to reencode files back and forth, just to view them properly. Not to say that the question is 5 years old and I thing Git didn't have `working-tree-encoding` 5 year ago.